# asyncio semaphore and wait task ordering patterns

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Consider the following code for managing concurrency with identical async tasks

```
import asyncio

async def performTask(id):

  await asyncio.sleep(1)
  print(id)


async def runBatchItem(semaphore, task):
  await semaphore.acquire()
  await task
  semaphore.release()


async def main():

  # all tasks
  tasks = [performTask(i) for i in range(20)]

  # concurrency handler
  MAX_CONCURRENT = 3
  semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(value=MAX_CONCURRENT)
  stasks = [runBatchItem(semaphore, task) for task in tasks]

  await asyncio.wait(stasks)


asyncio.run(main())
```

No matter how often I run it, I always end up with the following sequence of outputs

`3 19 4 5 6 7 8 17 9 10 11 12 13 0 14 1 15 2 16 18`

- Question 1. What is the logic to this ordering of my tasks?
- Question 2. What if I want the tasks to be processed in approximate insert order? I.e, like working through a queue with limited concurrency.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrew Svetlov (asyncio developer) answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40638143/13782669):

> The order is undetermenistic by `.wait()` specification.

If you start your script on another machine you will get different result. If you want impose an order on task execution, you can just `await` for them in a loop or use asyncio [synchronization primitive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html) such as `Event` or `Condition` within coroutines.